# How to resolve the "Your browser did something unexpected" error when logging into GitHub on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, github

I am having an issue with GitHub where when I try to submit certain things on the website it will shoot out the following error: "Your browser did something unexpected. Please contact us if the problem persists." I logged out of GitHub and now when I try and login, I am getting the error and cannot get back in.

Note this error is only occurring on my Chrome application and not on Microsoft Edge. I did clear the cache, cookies, data etc and restarted Chrome and the issue remains.

Anyone know of a good solution for this error or what is causing it in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check first if the issue persists, because the [incident yesterday](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/jzzxjt38k0d8) was about "elevated errors for Web and API requests."

Check also if you have 2FA activated (in which case, don't forget to use a personal access token as your password)

Finally, try and open Chrome without any plugin activated (`start chrome --disable-extensions`), to see if any plugin might have been interfering with the login process.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks VonC for your feedback! Turns out it was one extension in particular. Having the VPN application, Private Internet Access enabled, seems to cause issues with GitHub for some reason. Not sure why.

Comment: Yes, disabling MACE on the Private Internet Access extension fixes it

Answer (score 0):

check the browser's extensions and turn off Adblock or Adgurd any extensions that block advertising then, try again

Comment: Thank you for your response. This issue was answered last year and was indeed due to a browser extension; in this case associated with VPN.